# Using Hibernate criteria with restrictions from two entities, returning values from both as well

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have the following entities
    TaskType
      String id;
      String name;
      String description;
          ...

```
TaskQueue
  String id;
  String name;
  ...

TaskJBPM
  long id;
  String description;
  String status;
  String assignedToUser;
      int Priority;
  ...

Task
  String id;
  String name;
  long masterTaskId;    // Link to TaskJBPM table
  Date expectedStart;
  Date expectedEnd
  Date scheduledStart;
  Date scheduledEnd;
  String taskQueueId;    // Link to the TaskQueue table
  String taskTypeId;     // Link to the TaskType table
  ...
```

Inside of a hibernate criteria object I would like to be able to set restrictions using attributes from both the Task and TaskJBPM entities 
(eg.  criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("status", "created"),
      criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("name", "example");).

Also, I would like to return all of the attributes for both the Task and TaskJBPM tables (and maybe the attributes from TaskType and TaskQueue) as well.  Two questions.  Is this possible using a hibernate criteria object and is the performance going to be
'reasonable' when Task and TaskJBPM contain thousands of records? Can someone show me some
example code?
Thanks,
Fred

Answer (score 0):

It will be possible only if you design your entities correctly. This means that the Task entity shouldn't have a masterTaskId, a taskQueueId and a taskTypeId, but three (I suppose) ManyToOne associations:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "MASTER_TASK_ID")
private TaskJBPM masterTask;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "TASK_QUEUE_ID")
private TaskQueue taskQueue;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "TASK_TYPE_ID")
private TaskType taskType;
```

You will then be able to use joins (using `createAlias()` or `createCriteria()`) for your associations in the criteria query, and use projections to retrieve properties from all the entities.

The criteria query will translate to SQL. Its performance will not be worse than the SQL query you would have created yourself.